# Hook functions for Wp e-commerce?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am new to wp e-commerce plugin, I need the following hook function for this plugin

1. customer register success event
2. customer login
3. sales order place after
4. Hook function to change order shipping status from wp-admin end

I tried search, but could not found. Kindly advice

Comment: Did you try to open the plugin files in a code editor (notepad++, textmate, sublime, netbeans) and search for relevant keywords?

Comment: @brasofilo thanks,No i didnot try with files. I was checking here http://getshopped.org/resources/docs/get-involved/wpec-hooks-api/ I hope, there is hook for above event in wp ecommerce.For customer register, we can use theme by login hook http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/action-reference/

Comment: You should embed (not link) relevant info into the Question itself.

Answer (score 1):

1.customer register success event

WordPress: [user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

2.customer login

WordPress: [wp_login](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login)

3.sales order place after

WP E-Commerce: [wpsc_purchase_log_save](http://docs.getshopped.org/documentation/wpsc_purchase_log_save/)

4.Hook function to change order shipping status from wp-admin end

WP E-Commerce: [wpsc_update_purchase_log_status](http://docs.getshopped.org/documentation/wpsc_update_purchase_log_status/)

To identify the status:

```
INCOMPLETE_SALE  = 1;
ORDER_RECEIVED   = 2;
ACCEPTED_PAYMENT = 3;
JOB_DISPATCHED   = 4;
CLOSED_ORDER     = 5;
PAYMENT_DECLINED = 6;
REFUNDED         = 7;
REFUND_PENDING   = 8;
```